# Why do I get the previous pushed message from npm web-push to my chrome service-worker?

Tags: npm, google-chrome-extension, push-notification, service-worker, web-push

- I use a node server
- Installed npm package [web-push](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push)
- sending a POST request with payload that's pushing data with [sendNotification](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push#sendnotificationpushsubscription-payload-options)
- → ☠️ My problem happens here.
- Receiving the pushed message in the service worker [event listener](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/handling-messages)

So everything's working fine, except that I always get the previous message and the first time I get nothing.

1. server.sends **A** serviceWorker.receives **NOTHING**
2. server.sends **B** serviceWorker.receives **A**
3. server.sends **C** serviceWorker.receives **B**

```
//                  _         _                                    
//  _ __   ___   __| | ___   (_)___   ___  ___ _ ____   _____ _ __ 
// | '_ \ / _ \ / _` |/ _ \  | / __| / __|/ _ \ '__\ \ / / _ \ '__|
// | | | | (_) | (_| |  __/_ | \__ \ \__ \  __/ |   \ V /  __/ |   
// |_| |_|\___/ \__,_|\___(_)/ |___/ |___/\___|_|    \_/ \___|_|   
//                         |__/               

WEBPUSH.sendNotification(_receiver.sub, JSON.stringify(_payload)).catch(error => {
    console.error(error.stack);
    return !error;
});

//                      _                               _             
//  ___  ___ _ ____   _(_) ___ ___  __      _____  _ __| | _____ _ __ 
// / __|/ _ \ '__\ \ / / |/ __/ _ \ \ \ /\ / / _ \| '__| |/ / _ \ '__|
// \__ \  __/ |   \ V /| | (_|  __/  \ V  V / (_) | |  |   <  __/ |   
// |___/\___|_|    \_/ |_|\___\___|   \_/\_/ \___/|_|  |_|\_\___|_|   

self.addEventListener('push', e => {
    console.log('', {pushNotification:e, data:e.data.json()});
    self.toBackground({
        action: "pushNotification",
        payload: e.data.json()
    });
});
```